3rd column below the 2nd and move to below the 1st
I'm trying to do this :

I try flex but I can't find the solution.


.container {display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;}
.col1 {width: 50%; background-color: #ccc;}
.col2 {width: 50%; background-color: red;}
.col3 {width: 50%; background-color: yellow;}
/*@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
.col3 {width: 100%;}
}*/
<div class="container">
    <div class="col1">Content = image</div>
    <div class="col2">Content = text</div>
    <div class="col3">Content = text</div>
</div>




Flexbox cannot do this natively. Frankly this looks like a case for float.

Ok, is there another solution?

Can you describe what the difference in the content is between the two pictures you have shown? That is, why the gap in the second picture, what determines that?

Column 1 contains an image (which keeps its ratio), columns 2 and 3 contain text so the height will increase. On a wide screen the texts in columns 2 and 3 are approximately the height of the image, on less wide screens these texts are much higher. So I want the text in column 3 to go below columns 1 and 2 with a width of 100%.

What you're looking for can be done by using display: grid and specify areas. You can change the areas inside of your media query:


.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "one two"
    "one three";
}

.col-1 {
  background: red;
  grid-area: one;
}

.col-2 {
  background: green;
  grid-area: two;
}

.col-3 {
  background: lightblue;
  grid-area: three;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-areas: "one two"
      "three three";
  }
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-1">One</div>
  <div class="col-2">Two</div>
  <div class="col-3">Three</div>
</div>



